# Possible to trigger javascript animations inside an existing header element?

Tags: javascript, php, header, jquery-animate, move

I have a website with a php header for navigation and a separate element for content.
In the header there is a logo that links to the home page and social network buttons that do what you would expect them to.

So a standard web site.

Is it possible, on a particular page of the site, to treat the header as a background?

Or to put it another way,to have the company logo and the social network button become animated and also move around inside the header? And then fall down the page where they will become interactive.

I can animate objects inside the content element but I'm not sure how to have them overlayed on top of the header.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the header doesn't have overflow hidden and give those elements absolute positioning with a z-index. If the header needs overflow hidden you'l need to move those elements to the body or another parent node that doesn't have overflow hidden before they can appear outside of the header.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using css3's transform-property (in your case, you'll probably want translate).
That way you can move your elements around freely, ignoring any constraining parent elements.

As an example, applying

```
transform: translate(10px, 20px);
```

on any element, will move it 10px to right, and 20px down.

However you still have to keep an eye on overflow:hidden and z-indices, like Mica Williamson said.